# How to make button to fill 50% from the screen width in android?

Tags: android

I want to make the button to fill always `50%` from the width of the screen, as when I rotate the device horizontally or vertically always the button fill `50%` from the width.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

This should be possible by using weightSum and layout_weight:

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:weightSum="1.0">
 <Button
  android:id="@+id/textbox3"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight=".5"
  android:layout_width="0dip"
  android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

**To do this in code.**

```
// Get screen width.
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
final float width = metrics.widthPixels;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsWidth50 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    (int) (width/2) , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
textbox3.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsWidth50);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with Guideline:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_id"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:text="text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```